# How can one evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{3x^3-x^2+2x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}\mathrm dx$ using only elementary means?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How can one evaluate $$\int_0^1 \frac{3x^3-x^2+2x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}\mathrm dx$$ using only elementary means?

By *using only elementary means* I mean methods not exceeding the basic methods taught in a first course in the integral calculus. This is because I want an explanation accessible to secondary school students, as it was asked of me from a student, and I haven't so far come up with a simple way to evaluate this.

Thank you.

Comment: It has very simple closed form $$-\frac{101}{4\sqrt 2}+\frac{135}{32}\log\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt 2}{3-2\sqrt 2}\right)$$. There is more general result [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/355300697927549/permalink/2739948059462789/?app=fbl).

Comment: This integral is often asked in WhatsApps where  its value is supposed to be a password for an account at ATM!

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**: $(x^2-3x+2)'=2x-3$

now  write $$3x^3-x^2+2x-4=l(2x-3)(x^2-3x+2)+m(x^2-3x+2)+n(2x-3)+r$$ by comparing coefficents.....

Answer (score 1):

One way:
Let $3x^2-x^2+x-4=A(x^2-3x-2)(2x-3)+B(x^2-3x+4)+C(2x-3)+D.$
Find $A,B,C,D$ by comparing the coefficients of various powers of $x$. then
$$\int_0^1 \frac{3x^3-x^2+2x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx=A\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} ~(2x-3)~dx+B\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x^2-3x+2} ~dx+ C\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(2x-3)dx}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}+D\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}.$$
Solve first and third  integrals by letting $2x-3=t$, second and fourth integra;ls are standard.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

We make the integrand clearer by depleting the denominator with the change of variable $2x-3=t$.

The integral becomes

$$\int_{-3}^{-1}\frac{3t^3+25t^2+77t+55}{8\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$$ and this calls for the change of variable $\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}=-du$, or $t=-\cosh(u)$. (The negative sign is demanded by the integration bounds.)

The term $\cosh^3(u)$ is easy to integrate as $\cosh(u)(\sinh^2(u)+1)$, and $\cosh^2(u)$ as $\dfrac{\cosh(2u)+1}2$. The rest is routine work.